# Can we combine update and select queries in mysql 5.5?

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

I have a table like this in which in want to update and select at same time.

```
CREATE TABLE ABCD_TABLE(ID VARCHAR(17) ,MAC VARCHAR(25),STATE SMALLINT,REGISTERED_MAC TEXT,TIME TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO ABCD_TABLE
    (`id`, `MAC`, `STATE`, `REGISTERED_MAC`, TIME)
VALUES
    (1, 'AB12CD65',"1",'NULL', NOW()),
    (2, 'BCSH9088',"2",'NULL', NOW()),
    (3, 'NHGTF5TT',"3",'NULL', NOW())
    ;
```

Can we combine these queries

```
update abcd_table
     set state = (case when state = 9 then 4 else state end),
         time = now()
     where id = "1";

     select REGISTERED_MAC FROM ABCD_TABLE WHERE STATE = "4" and id = "1";
```

Comment: Do you want to `Update` and then `Select` updated values?

Comment: @genespos What i want to do is for a row identified by "id" if the "state" gets updated then i want the "registered_mac" value for that.

Comment: Please edit and clarify your question

Comment: It's not often that a one word answer will suffice: No.